# Bundle install - endless error message + can't install eventmachine or rake

Tags: ruby, rake, bundle, bundler, eventmachine

This is what I'm using: Windows 8. Cygwin32. Rvm version 1.25.27. Ruby version 2.1.2p95. Gem version 2.3.0. Drush version 5.9. Bundler version 1.6.3. My gem list looks like this:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

addressable (2.3.6)
bigdecimal (1.2.5, 1.2.4)
breakpoint (2.0.7)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.6.3)
celluloid (0.15.2)
chunky_png (1.3.1)
coderay (1.1.0)
color-schemer (0.2.8)
compass (0.12.6)
compass-blend-modes (0.0.2)
compass-normalize (1.5)
compass-rgbapng (0.2.1)
compass-validator (3.0.1)
css_parser (1.3.5)
dash (0.4.0)
fssm (0.2.10)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (5.3.5, 4.7.5)
psych (2.0.5)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.1, 4.1.0)
sass (3.2.19)
test-unit (2.5.5, 2.1.2.0)
timers (1.1.0)
```

I am trying to use "drush omega-guard" but only end up with errors. First it tells me to run "bundle install".

```
$ drush omega-guard
Which theme do you want to run Guard for?
 [0]  :  Cancel
 [1]  :  Ohm (Subtheme of Omega) - Omega based demonstration theme. Serves as a
         best-practice reference for the Omega documentation. Ohm will be
         constantly updated as best practice evolves so shouldn't be used in
         production.
 [2]  :  Omega - A powerful HTML5 base theme framework utilizing tools like
         Sass, Compass, Grunt, Bower, Ruby Version Manager, Bundler and more.
 [3]  :  Design (Subtheme of Omega) - Please provide a description for
         your theme.

3
There was a problem with your setup:                                 [error]
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler can't satisfy your Gemfile's dependencies.
Install missing gems with `bundle install`.
```

So I try running "bundle install". When I do I end up with an endless error message where the last two lines keep repeating themself over and over, but with different numbers every time.

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using addressable 2.3.6
Using chunky_png 1.3.1
Using fssm 0.2.10
Using sass 3.2.19
Using compass 0.12.6
Using breakpoint 2.0.7
Using timers 1.1.0
Using celluloid 0.15.2
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using compass-blend-modes 0.0.2
Using color-schemer 0.2.8
Using compass-normalize 1.5
Using compass-rgbapng 0.2.1
Using compass-validator 3.0.1
Using css_parser 1.3.5
0 [main] ruby 12988 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'fcntl.so' (0x760000) is already occupied
0 [main] ruby 7192 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'date_core.so' (0x5A0000) is already occupied
```

So I press ctrl+C to cancel it and end up with this:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/I/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Resource temporarily unavailable - /home/I/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb  2>&1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/I/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/I/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86-cygwin/2.1.0/eventmachine-1.0.3/gem_make.out
```

Then the endless error message continue again so I press ctrl+C once more and get this:

```
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I try "gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3' I get the endless errormessage again, which I once again cancel with ctrl+C:

```
$ gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
      0 [main] ruby 3396 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'fcntl.so' (0x380000) is already occupied
      0 [main] ruby 7192 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'date_core.so' (0x5A0000) is already occupied

ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/I/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Resource temporarily unavailable - /home/I/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 2>&1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/I/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/I/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86-cygwin/2.1.0/eventmachine-1.0.3/gem_make.out
```

I found a instruction on how to install eventmachine and I tried it out. It said to follow thees steps:

```
git clone git://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git
cd eventmachine
rake gem
gem install pkg/eventmachine-0.12.3.gem
gem install thin rack
```

(http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/289-how-to-install-thin-rack-and-eventmachine-on-windows-cygwin) I try it out and get this:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git
Cloning into 'eventmachine'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 4744, done.
remote: Total 4744 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (4744/4744), 2.04 MiB | 44 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2607/2607), done.

I@I ~/.rvm/gems
$ cd eventmachine

I@I ~/.rvm/gems/eventmachine
$ rake gem
rake-compiler gem seems to be missing. Please install it with

  gem install rake-compiler

(add sudo if necessary).
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::ExtensionTask
/home/I/.rvm/gems/eventmachine/rakelib/package.rake:44:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

I@I ~/.rvm/gems/eventmachine
$ gem install rake-compiler
Fetching: rake-compiler-0.9.2.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

I am really trying to solve my problems on my own but I'm getting kind of desperate. As soon as one problem is fixed another occur. I'm totally new to all of this and all I want to do is to be able to run "drush omega-guard" so I can continue follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZw8J1zfzZk&index=9&list=PLLnpHn493BHH5nnK2dKE_42l1oXA6Tq6H I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Have you tried `bundle exec drush omega-guard`?

Comment: I hadn't tried it before so I tried it now and (of course) I got a new error. I get to chose which theme I want to run Guard for and then it says "You have to install Rubygems version 1.8 or newer.". So I tried running "which rubygems" but got no result so I used cd to get to the folder where I know (or at least think I know) that rubygems is installed. But "which rubygems" give no result there either. However when I type  "ruby setup.rb" which it says I should do here: https://rubygems.org/pages/download it says "RubyGems 2.3.0 installed". So why do I get an error saying it's not installed?

Comment: What does `gem --version` say?

Comment: $ gem --version
2.3.0